# CID en tag background-image html no funciona

Tags: html, css

Estoy embebiendo una imagen de fondo en un email de esta forma pero no funciona, ya que no me muestra la imagen

```html
<div style='position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;background-image:url(\"cid:back1\");'>        HOLA      </ div >
```

cuando embebo la imagen con un tag img si me muestra la imagen

```html
<img  src=\"cid:back1\"' width='30' height='30' style='display: block;'>
```

¿se puede embeber en tag backgroud-image?

Comment: Prueba usando un servidor de imágenes como imgur o desde una ruta estática si tienes un dominio propio... _https://tu_dominio.com/images/email_background.png_

Comment: @DjCrazy si me muestra la imagen pero como imagen adjunta al correo, no la posiciona como background